# Linearize product of three variables (one binary, two non-negative)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, linearization

I have $h = xyz$, with $x \in \{0,1\}$, $y \in [0,T]$ and $z \in [0,S]$. The constants $T$ and $S$ are non-negative. Is there any method to linearize $h = xyz$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not if you mean linearize in the sense of converting it to an equivalent logic model. The bilinear product $yz$ is inherently nonlinear.